# How to select where json like array of keys and values via Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have MySQL table with json field:

```php
Schema::create('meta', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->json('details');
});
```

and array of key and values:

```php
$filter = ['key' => 'val', 'id' => 'val'];
```

How to select rows where json containing keys and values from array?

This don't works:

```php
Meta::where('details', $filter)->get();
```

```php
Meta::whereJsonContains('details', $filter)->get();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this post could give you some idea:https://medium.com/@thakuramit3/laravel-provides-an-efficient-way-to-handle-json-column-in-the-table-with-its-magical-tool-a957c13004bf

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

```php
Meta::where(function($query) use($filter) {
    foreach($filter as $k => $v) {
        $query->orWhere("details->{$k}", $v);
    }
})->get();
```

But it will not work with deep nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses)

> To query a JSON column, use the -> operator:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('options->language', 'en')
                ->get();

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('preferences->dining->meal', 'salad')
                ->get();
```

Comment: I know this, the problem is different. Re-read the question again.

Comment: Is it deeply nested?

Comment: I don't know the names of the keys and their depth, I just have an array with some keys and values.

Comment: I think your own answer is the best one for this solution. As for the deep nesting issue you can make it into a recursive function. Otherwise I think re-thinking your database design is the best option. :)

Comment: It is strange that such a possibility is not built into the Eloquent. For non-json-wheres such is out of the box.